# Change IPv4 settings automatically when AP changes

Tags: windows, networking, dns, dhcp, ipv4

Is there a way to configure an adapter's IPv4 settings (IP address, gateway, DNS) to change per Access Point (either wireless or ethernet) instead of having them fixed by adapter only?

I'd feel comfortable with scripting and using the task scheduler to achieve this if there is no out-of-the-box solution. So far I've found [netprofiles](https://github.com/netprofilesmod/netprofilesmod/releases), but I'd like to avoid third-party software if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: How are the addresses assigned? DHCP would do this automatically. But, typically you don’t change the IP address if the APs are part of the same network.

Comment: This is my problem. On a network I use a static IP address and static DNS servers, but on the other one I use DHCP for both, and I don't want to be changing adapter's settings twice a day.

Comment: You can definitely script this with `netsh` command. Powershell I’m sure has a way too.

Comment: Can I automate it too with task scheduler somehow? Can you give me some hints in the right direction?